# Magento2.3 How to remove estimation call on state change action in Cart page?

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.3, shipping

I need to remove estimation call on state change action in the cart page. When user change region estimation call execute when to add zip code than  estimation call execute again, so shipping calculation takes a too much time.

So How I can achieve it?